# Angular UI $modal error

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I have downloaded some of the angular UI directives, as i do not need them all.  I have downloaded the latest file for modal from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and using this code

```
App.controller('PagesController', ['$scope', '$modal', 'PageFactory', function ($scope, $modal, PageFactory) {

    $scope.pages = [];

    PageFactory.getPages().then(function (pages) {
        $scope.pages = pages;
    }, function (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    });

    $scope.deletePage = function (page) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'pages-delete-modal.html',
            controller: ['$scope', '$modalInstance', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
                $scope.ok = function () {
                    $modalInstance.close();
                };

                $scope.cancel = function () {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };
            }]
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function () {
            // ok selected

        }, function () {

        });
    };

}]);
```

Here is the template

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="pages-delete-modal.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Delete Confirmation</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        Are you sure you want to delete this page?
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="ok()">Delete</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

Now i seem to get an error saying

```
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$injector/unpr?p0=%24modalProvider%20%3C-%20%24modal
```

I already have 'ui.bootstrap' injected into my app.js file here as you can see

```
var App = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

If i however use this link, instead of using the downloaded modal file, it works?

```
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.js"></script>
```

I have also downloaded the transition directive as i believe the modal directive is dependant on this, but i cannot see that i am missing anything else.

I am using the tpl.min.js files for both transition and modal.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Add the code of control definition too, like angular.module('myApp').control('controlName',function($scope) ...

Comment: not sure what you mean... I have updated my post to include the full controller code.

Answer (score 0):

You should try change the modalInstance controller to a string with the name of an actual controller in your project.

```
$scope.deletePage = function (page) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'pages-delete-modal.html',
        controller: 'otherCtrl'
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function () {
        // ok selected

    }, function () {

    });
};
```

and then create the controller itself

```
App.controller('otherCtrl',['$scope','$modalInstance', function($scope,$modalInstance){

    $scope.ok = function () {
       $modalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
       $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}]);
```